# Cannot log in to 2008 Server using UPN suffix. Domain\User works fine

Tags: windows-server-2008, rdp, active-directory

I'm running Windows 2008 Server and Windows Seven on ESXi using pfSense to have a NAT Network.

I just set up Active Directory and DNS in Windows 2008, I tried to add UPN to my configuration, but when I try to RDP connect using @myupn it's not working.

Normal RDP login is working using DOMAIN\User, but not user@myupn.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In Windows server 2008, it is technically possible for you to specify different values for the UPN and the NetBIOS username.  Check the UPN and see what you get.  Ensure it is correct (and set), and see what you get.

You can specify a UPN a number of ways, also.  You can specify user@subdomain, user@subdomain.domain, and user@subdomain.domain.tld.  For instance, if you have a domain registered to your organization example.com, your domain's NetBIOS name would be EXAMPLE by default; some organizations may configure it EXAMPLECOM.  You would normally specify, in this case, EXAMPLECOM\username but also username@example.com.

It may also be that your RDP target cannot contact the DC, so it can't resolve the UPN, but if it has cached credentials for the NB username, it will still take that.

Comment: I double checked my UPN and it seems legit to me, I still can't connect using user@domain.com while DOMAIN\user works

Comment: I wonder if for some reason the RDP target can't contact your DC, and is trying to use cached credentials?  If so, it is not able to map the UPN to the cached credentials or SID locally, and needs to contact the DC for this.

Comment: I tried to reboot and still not working, when i try to ping mydomain.com it's not working

Comment: @Tempy Sounds like you have a connectivity problem.

Comment: Indeed.  I added the last paragraph to address this.  If you can't ping mydomain.com, that is exactly what is happening.

Comment: How can I fix this ? I put the win server IP in the DNS configuration on the windows 7.

Comment: Can you ping that IP?  You will also need a few ports open... I can't recall exactly which, but you should be able to at least contact it on 53 and 389, and possibly 636 as well.

Comment: Yeah I can ping that IP, I can rdp on that IP, just can't connect using user@domain.com

Comment: If you can ping the DC's IP but cannot ping the domain name, you have a DNS issue (probably 90% of AD issues are really DNS issues).

Comment: I went to Active directory Domains and Trusts, then right click on properties and added a UPN, do I need to do something else ?

Comment: Huh?  You can add alternate UPNs, but you have to define them for the user too.  I doubt this is much related to your problem.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'm totally new to Win2008 and AD, I'll try to find how to add UPN to an account